# Custom Post Type rewrite slug always takes me to homepage

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I know there are number of posts already available here regarding this particular issue and I have gone through a number of them but could not make my page to work. So I want to put here what I exactly have and looking forward to a solution.

I have registered the following Custom Post Type.

```
$labels = array('name' => 'Hotel','singular_name' => 'Hotel','admin_menu' => 'Hotel', 'name_admin_bar' => 'Hotel');

$supports = array(
    'title',
    'editor',
    'thumbnail'
);

$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'taxonomies' => array ('hotel_type', 'room_type', 'amenities'),
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'menu_position' => 28,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'hotels'),
    'supports' => $supports,
    'exclude_from_search' => false
);

register_post_type('hotel-info', $args);
```

Created a template page called `hotel-list.php`

Created a page using the above template (List of Hotels) in admin called `Staying Options` and updated its permalink to `/hotels/`.

Re-saved permalink structure from Settings > Permalink

But whenever I am trying to access `http://local.tourplanner.com/hotels/` WordPress is taking me back to my homepage.

Somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong.

**EDIT:**
When I am accessing `http://local.tourplanner.com/hotels/cliff-top-club-auli/` I am able to land on the correct page with information about the hotel.

Answer (score 1):

You have created a slug only for individual hotels, and not for all hotels. Wordpress simply doesn't know how to list your hotels.

In order to make `/hotels/` accessible, you'll need to create an archive page, which will be used to list the hotels. First have a quick look at the Post Type Template documentation here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates. Then follow the guide on how to create the archive page here http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-post-types-archive-page-in-wordpress/

Comment: Thank you for your quick response and sharing tutorial links! I will go though them soon.